# Change datatype from DATE to VARCHAR()

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure create_table_dateWise27()

LANGUAGE plpgsql

as $$

declare 

d_date date;

begin

    select to_char(current_timestamp :: timestamp - interval '1 hour','yyyy-mm-
dd')into d_date;

EXECUTE format('
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I(
    nodeip text,
    interface text, 
    nodeip_interface text
   )','test_'|| d_date-1);

commit;

end;
$$; 

call create_table_dateWise27();
```

I want to perform the same operation where d_date is a VARCHAR().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put yesterday's date into the variable then do it during assignment. And if you want a varchar, then declare it as one - your current code does an implicit and useless conversion back a varchar back to a `date` anyway.

So something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure create_table_dateWise27()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $$
declare 
  d_date varchar;
begin

  d_date := to_char(current_date - 1, 'yyyy_mm_dd'); --<< yesterday

  EXECUTE format('
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I(
      nodeip text,
      interface text, 
      nodeip_interface text
    )','test_'|| d_date);

  commit;
end;
$$;
```

Note that I changed the format mask for the `to_char()` call to use underscores (`_`)  rather than `-` because a dash is invalid in an SQL identifier (table name) and thus would require the use of a [quoted identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) which you should really avoid.